Assign value to all rows based on condition being fulfilled or not
I have a table with different columns that include the ID, Year of observation and the value observed. For simplicity, the following is a small sample that conveys my problem:
df = data.frame(
ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3), Year=c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014, 2010,2011,2012,2013,2014), 
Value = c(1,1,0,0,0, 0,1,1,1,1, 1,0,0,0,0)
)

My goal is that grouping by ID, in a new column, let's call it NewCol, if Year == 2012 & Value == 0 then NewCol = 0 and else 1. Getting that part I have no problem, however, I want the rest of NewCol filled with the same value (Either 1s or 0s) according to the condition set. And it would looked like this:
data.frame(
ID=c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,3),
Year=c(2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014, 2010,2011,2012,2013,2014), 
Value = c(1,1,0,0,0, 0,1,1,1,1, 1,0,0,0,0), 
NewCol = c(0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
)

I have tried:
df %>% group_by(ID) %>% mutate(NewCol = ifelse(Year == 2012 & Value == 0, 0, 1))
but it only works for the one row that satisfies the condition.
I tried this but as mentioned from the comment by zack with >1 it does not work.
Appreaciate any help.

You can wrap your condition by any() so that it returns a single logical value per group.
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(NewCol = ifelse(any(Year == 2012 & Value == 0), 0, 1))

# A tibble: 15 × 4
# Groups:   ID [3]
      ID  Year Value NewCol
   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1  2010     1      0
 2     1  2011     1      0
 3     1  2012     0      0
 4     1  2013     0      0
 5     1  2014     0      0
 6     2  2010     0      1
 7     2  2011     1      1
 8     2  2012     1      1
 9     2  2013     1      1
10     2  2014     1      1
11     3  2010     1      0
12     3  2011     0      0
13     3  2012     0      0
14     3  2013     0      0
15     3  2014     0      0


This works perfectly, thank you! Just couldn´t manage to do it. To understand better what any() does, would you say its role is: if any row from the ID falls under the condition defined then all the rows of that particular ID will equal 0, otherwise 1.

@JoseMM You got it :)

Great, thanks again. I have marked it as accepted.
